# Retrieving field subset in ruby with mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a nested document "player" inside a document called "team". I want to find team per ID and list only the names of the players in the team in mongoid. I tried something like

```
Team.find(id).projection({'players.name':1}).to_json
```

But apparently the projection method is not available anymore? I am using mongoid 7.0.0

Comment: Take a look the [Mongoid query docs](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html), it seems there is a `pluck` method and also `select` in Moped. I'm not sure exactly how you'd adapt this to your situation but hopefully it's a starting place.

Comment: Thanks, I already checked. If I use Team.find(id), I can't pluck that. Pluck is called on Mongoid::Criteria. After filtering, a normal class "Team" is returned

Comment: what about usinng `where` instead?

Comment: Yes, this did the job! thanks!

Comment: feel free to add your own answer showing the code that ended up working for you.